# Using Induction proof to find that $x_{n}<4$ for all $n \ge1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Hey guys I'm not understanding induction proofs too well, the question asks

Consider the sequence of real numbers defined by the relations:

$x_{1} = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+2x_{n}}$ for all $n \ge 1$

Use mathematical induction to show that $x_{n} < 4$ for all $n \ge 1 $

I'm by no means looking for an answer, I'm hoping one of you guys could help me with a step by step method on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{1 + 2\cdot 4} = \sqrt{9} = 3 < 4$.

Comment: Hint:$ f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$ is an increasing function for $x\ge0$. So if $a<b$ then $\sqrt{1+2a}<\sqrt{1+2b}$. Think of $a=x_n$ and $b=4$.

Answer (score 0):

The goal with induction is to show that if a property holds for the $n$th term in a sequence, then it holds for the $(n+1)$th term. In our example, suppose $x_n < 4$. Does $x_{n+1} < 4$ follow? As an old professor of mine used to say, "just follow your nose":
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1} &= \sqrt{1 + 2x_n}\\
&< \sqrt{1 + 2 \cdot 4}\\
&= \sqrt{9}\\
&= 3
\end{align*}
By this line of reasoning, $x_1 < 4$ implies $x_2 < 4$, which implies $x_3 < 4$, and so on forever. (In fact, it looks like you could get a much better upper bound than 4.)